# How to properly open a new window on JQuery AJAX Success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get a dynamically generated link to open after an ajax request (Specifically after success is returned from the AJAX call). I have a partially working code which works on desktop Chrome and Firefox, but it doesn't work on mobile Safari (the window is not opened.)

Here is the code (simplified for clarity purposes):

```js
//this function gets called by a click event
function go(){

  var generatedurl
  // generatedurl gets generated

  $.ajax({
      url:'url.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {data},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
                if (data.status == 'success'){
                  gofunction();
                } 
                else if (data.status == 'error') {
                    alert("error");
                } 
      },
      error: function(){
        alert("error");
      }
    });

  function gofunction()  { 
      window.open(generatedurl, '_blank');
      location.reload();
    }

}
```

I am aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696041/window-openurl-blank-not-working-on-imac-safari), however when i try to apply it to my code, like this:

```js
//this function gets called by a click event
function go(){

  var generatedurl
  // generatedurl gets generated

  var windowReference = window.open(); //this was added

  $.ajax({
      url:'url.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {data},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
                if (data.status == 'success'){
                  gofunction();
                } 
                else if (data.status == 'error') {
                    alert("error");
                } 
      },
      error: function(){
        alert("error");
      }
    });

  function gofunction()  { 
      windowReference.location = url; //this was changed
      location.reload();
    }

}
```

For some reason it opens the link even when an error is returned, also `location.reload();` doesnt fire.

I'd be thankful for any pointers on what would be the best approach.

Comment: This will always open the new window,  var windowReference = window.open(); //this was added

Comment: Yep i got it.  The answer i linked states:  `Opening a new tab in Safari on iOS just works from an async function, just make sure you create the window (window.open) before calling the async call`. But i'm not sure on how to apply it to this case

Comment: Put it in the go function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a follow up for those having the same issue: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223388/window-open-works-different-on-ajax-success) answer provided a working solution to my issue.

So, my working code is as follows:

```js
//this function gets called by a click event
function go(){

  var go_success = false;  //THIS LINE WAS ADDED

  var generatedurl
  // generatedurl gets generated

  $.ajax({
      url:'url.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {data},
      dataType: "json",
      async:false,   //THIS LINE WAS ADDED
      success: function(data) {
                if (data.status == 'success'){
                  go_success = true; //THIS LINE WAS CHANGED
                } 
                else if (data.status == 'error') {
                    alert("error");
                } 
      },
      error: function(){
        alert("error");
      }
    });

   if(go_success)  {  //THIS LINE WAS CHANGED
      window.open(generatedurl, '_blank');
      location.reload();
    }

}
```